# Set checkedListBox item checked if valuemember = something

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, checkedlistbox

I know how to set item to checked:

```
checkedListBox.SetItemChecked(index, true);
```

but i am having it called when i am opening form with parameter of `int[] valueMembers` so i want to check every value member that is = to this parameter to checked. Here is what i have tried:

```
    public NovaPoruka(int[] primalacID)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        foreach(CheckedListBox o in checkedListBox1.Items)
        {
            if(primalacID.Contains(Convert.ToInt32(o.SelectedValue)))
            {
                o.SetItemChecked(o.SelectedIndex, true);
            }
        }
    }
```

Edit:
I haven't seen that i didn't initialize `checkedListBox` before doing this so it wasn't dropping error but now when i made that i drops me error at `CheckedListBox o in checkedListBox1.Items` so i made little change but still do not know how to get index of current item that is inside foreach loop. Here is changed code:

```
foreach(Int_String o in checkedListBox1.Items)
{
    if(primalacID.Contains(Convert.ToInt32(o._int)))
    {
            checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(checkedListBox1.SelectedIndex, true);
    }
}
```

current way of getting selected index returns me `-1`

Comment: And? what is the problem? Did you forget to explain why this code is not working?

Comment: It just don't. It doesn't check it and doesn't drop any error

Comment: I have made some edit so it may be easier for you

Comment: Use a normal for... loop and your index is the variable used in the for iteration

Comment: Just have done it and was answering. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it. Here is final code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
{
    Int_String s = checkedListBox1.Items[i] as Int_String;
    if(primalacID.Contains(s._int))
    {
        checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(i, true);
    }
}
```